# package.xml -- standard fields aren't supported, including system fields

Tags: metadata-api, package.xml

I am reading this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to interpret this block of text:

> This sample package.xml manifest file illustrates how to work with the standard Account object. Retrieving or deploying a standard object includes all custom and standard fields except for standard fields that aren’t customizable. All custom fields are supported. Only standard fields that you can customize are supported, that is, standard fields to which you can add help text or enable history tracking or Chatter feed tracking. Other standard fields aren't supported, including system fields (such as `CreatedById` or `LastModifiedDate`) and autonumber fields.

Does this mean, when I use something like Force.com CLI to retrieve an object, I have no way to fetch the `CreatedById` or `LastModifiedDate` fields?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Knowing your end goal may be helpful in steering you towards the right answer.

Comment: My company is using trial Salesforce accounts, to develop our integration with Salesforce (we sell data to companies that use Salesforce). I'm trying to avoid the situation where our 30 day trial ends, and I have to re-create all the data in a new account. When one of our 30 day trials ends, I want to be able to run something like "force export" and get everything I need, so that when I open the new account, I simply run "force import" and the new account suddenly has everything that the old account had. But I'm not sure how to handle the CreatedById field.

Comment: You certainly cannot set audit fields without opening a case with support. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176484&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

You can still use SOQL to query records and get values for those fields.

What that means is that those fields will not be pulled down and can't be updated using the object metadata. The .object file will not contain a field definition for those fields.